# Does GPG encryption via subkey harm file quality?

Tags: encryption, gnupg, file-encryption

If I were to encrypt a folder with music files or movie files, or even only the files themselves separately, would that hurt the quality of the files? For example, if I encrypted a lossless audio file, and decrypted it right after, would it lose quality or would it be the exact same file?

Comment: This could be verified very quickly by hashing before and after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind encryption is that the original can be restored by decrypting again, that means that the process is lossless and thus the quality of the "file" is not harmed.